# Why has question 16544 been put on hold once again?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16544/is-allah-wearing-a-loincloth-as-stated-in-sahih-bukhari-book-65-hadith-4879?noredirect=1#comment31611_16544) has been put on hold once again. Can somebody tell me why this had to happen?

Comment: I already left a comment explaining my closure.  If that is unclear to you, please elaborate this question to explain exactly what you don't understand.